# Is anyone else have issue deleting AWS Glacier archives?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I've been following the instructions on the AWS Docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/getting-started-delete-archive-cli.html and it works up until the last command where I delete the archive by its ID.

The command executes fine but the archive still in the vault, is there a time delay between `aws glacier delete-archive` and the archive actually getting deleted?

`aws --debug glacier delete-archive --vault-name test-vault --account-id 1234567890 --archive-id "XIEYSpXAEcTO27fXXREDyb4BssF-nZPi8sIIyvqqfDFXkO4zBdeFfPRBgqmXaRJPGwmpdllkwWpBRtNocrVZv4Q6yJLwCDym6wELMsVw_ZDQq9_WnUE6ufgPT0Le-364s-HGyh47Qw"`

```
2021-02-20 16:37:15,290 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=DeleteArchive) with params: {'url_path': '/1234567890/vaults/test-vault/archives/XIEYSpXAEcTO27fXXREDyb4BssF-nZPi8sIIyvqqfDFXkO4zBdeFfPRBgqmXaRJPGwmpdllkwWpBRtNocrVZv4Q6yJLwCDym6wELMsVw_ZDQq9_WnUE6ufgPT0Le-364s-HGyh47Qw', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'DELETE', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/2.0.38 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64 command/glacier.delete-archive', 'x-amz-glacier-version': '2012-06-01'}, 'body': b'', 'url': ' 'context': {'client_region': 'eu-west-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7fd5e7a9d8d0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2021-02-20 16:37:15,290 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.glacier.DeleteArchive: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7fd5e7a9d790>>
2021-02-20 16:37:15,291 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.glacier.DeleteArchive: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7fd5e67118c0>
2021-02-20 16:37:15,291 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2021-02-20 16:37:15,291 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
DELETE
/1234567890/vaults/test-vault/archives/XIEYSpXAEcTO27fXXREDyb4BssF-nZPi8sIIyvqqfDFXkO4zBdeFfPRBgqmXaRJPGwmpdllkwWpBRtNocrVZv4Q6yJLwCDym6wELMsVw_ZDQq9_WnUE6ufgPT0Le-364s-HGyh47Qw

host:glacier.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20210220T163715Z
x-amz-glacier-version:2012-06-01

host;x-amz-date;x-amz-glacier-version
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
2021-02-20 16:37:15,291 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20210220T163715Z
20210220/eu-west-1/glacier/aws4_request
3ac54f35e66fba13673a078b721c5db02a9f00c538bd96fc5b2d5b5709926b75
2021-02-20 16:37:15,292 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
1a09aef04ae7830ae5a7623cedb6ca69bf8cdef7349e3f3493a116967ba03110
2021-02-20 16:37:15,292 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=DELETE, url=https://glacier.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/1234567890/vaults/test-vault/archives/XIEYSpXAEcTO27fXXREDyb4BssF-nZPi8sIIyvqqfDFXkO4zBdeFfPRBgqmXaRJPGwmpdllkwWpBRtNocrVZv4Q6yJLwCDym6wELMsVw_ZDQq9_WnUE6ufgPT0Le-364s-HGyh47Qw, headers={'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/2.0.38 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64 command/glacier.delete-archive', 'x-amz-glacier-version': b'2012-06-01', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20210220T163715Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Access Key Removed>/20210220/eu-west-1/glacier/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-glacier-version, Signature=1a09aef04ae7830ae5a7623cedb6ca69bf8cdef7349e3f3493a116967ba03110', 'Content-Length': '0'}>
2021-02-20 16:37:15,294 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): glacier.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443
2021-02-20 16:37:15,510 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://glacier.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 "DELETE /1234567890/vaults/test-vault/archives/XIEYSpXAEcTO27fXXREDyb4BssF-nZPi8sIIyvqqfDFXkO4zBdeFfPRBgqmXaRJPGwmpdllkwWpBRtNocrVZv4Q6yJLwCDym6wELMsVw_ZDQq9_WnUE6ufgPT0Le-364s-HGyh47Qw HTTP/1.1" 204 0
2021-02-20 16:37:15,511 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amzn-RequestId': 'mR_DR8mtULOgCU0FDDv_aec7eYp34-QtXBONWBtWXjH1yts', 'Date': 'Sat, 20 Feb 2021 16:37:15 GMT'}
2021-02-20 16:37:15,511 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b''
2021-02-20 16:37:15,511 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.glacier.DeleteArchive: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x7fd5e7aef190>>
2021-02-20 16:37:15,512 - MainThread - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2021-02-20 16:37:15,512 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.glacier.DeleteArchive: calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker object at 0x7fd5e7a9dc50>>
2021-02-20 16:37:15,521 - MainThread - awscli.formatter - DEBUG - RequestId: mR_DR8mtULOgCU0FDDv_aec7eYp34-QtXBONWBtWXjH1yts
```

It's been over an hour since I executed the delete command and the vault still have the archive on it.

Has anyone had this issue? or does anyone know how I can delete a vault fully?

### Update

The console allows me to delete but fails with the vault not being empty.

[image]

*ps: I've posted this on AWS Forum as well but that's always slow at getting answers, so I'm trying my luck here. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=335827*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Deleting an Archive in Amazon S3 Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/deleting-an-archive.html):

> After you delete an archive, if you immediately download the vault
> inventory, it might include the deleted archive in the list because S3
> Glacier prepares vault inventory only about once a day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would that be also the case in the Console as well? I can't still delete the vault from AWS Console either.

Comment: The console isn't really any different to the awscli or SDKs. They all rely on the same source of information from the underlying S3 service. Does the console actually give you the option to delete the vault but it then fails (what is the error message?) or does the console prevent you from even attempting to delete the vault?

Comment: Yeah, I can delete the vault but it fails with **Vault not empty or recently written to**. To be honest, this is my first time dealing with Glacier so I'm expecting all actions to work as other resources in AWS so that might be wrong. I'm just trying to figure out what's the time frame of things happening in Glacier.

Comment: These days, it is much easier (and actually cheaper!) to use Glacier via S3. In the beginning, this option was not available. If you are going to use Glacier directly, it is easiest to use 3rd-party tools that understand it (eg Cloudberry).

Comment: This is a mess made by Synology NAS about 5 years ago now I'm having to deal with. I've a vault with 125786 archives that I need to delete as well. This gonna turn into a nightmare to me at that point. Since I don't need the data I just need to get the delete archive thing to work, if not I'll have to use something like Cloudberry as you suggested.

Comment: It actually takes a day to update after deleting archives, today it was empty. Thanks, guys for the help.